# Attach hidden options to a file in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, filenames, filepath

So I want to attach some secret info to my files in a program, and VS2013 throws an exception stating:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The specified path format is not supported.
```

For the lines:

```
string metafile = filename + ":key";
StreamWriter metadata = new StreamWriter(metafile);
```

How can I solve this? I need it, because this way I can check it with console with the command: "notepad file.txt:key".

Comment: How would an addition to the filename be secret? you could add an excrypted string but notepad would not be able to test it..

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/281313). I don't think an obscurely named/hidden file is a proper way to save options for your program. What about the registry, or a visible (but encrypted) file instead?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8zeh7y this is what I'm talking about, I want to access this kind of file extension. Also in the code "filename + ":key.txt" throws the same exception...

Comment: There is no indication that notepad did access any such file.

Answer (score 1):

That StreamWriter constructor will try to open the file with the name of the string you're passing to it (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b(v=vs.110).aspx) -- assuming this is a Windows system, file names can't contain colons, hence the "path format not supported" exception.

Maybe try an underscore instead of a colon, i.e.:

```
string metafile = filename + "_key";
```

Comment: The file.txt:a creates a hidden "file" to the program, which can be opened with console, and it's moved with the file. So if I create a.txt:a and move it somewhere else, with the name b.txt:a it will have the same content.

Comment: Point is that Windows generally can't do that. (I assume we're talking Windows here, if not then it's another story!) There are some ways around it (you can echo to a file with otherwise illegal characters in it, for example -- e.g. "echo something > file:illegal.txt") but if there's a way to do that in C# I'm not aware of it. Managed code probably won't allow it.

If nothing else, it sounds like you're going for security by obscurity, which usually has limited success -- as some others have suggested, you may be better off with some type of encryption. Regardless, good luck!

Comment: After a  half-hour using google, wikipedia, etc i found an interesting entry about it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28file_system%29#Microsoft